# how to "reset" the console in chrome to see the vscode commands such as regular console.log('hi')

Tags: google-chrome, console, google-developers-console

I had re inatalled chrome and reset the console mith the defulte setting , I am still not seeing the results in the console when i first started using it, could it be an exstension or something ?

in the image you should be seeing 'Hi' but not sure why its not showing it.

what I did:
re installing chrome and re setting console setting (Looking for answer in web but not seeing answer there) , I was excpecting it to just go back to what it was before.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1rHM.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try select all levels of logs instead of default

Comment: its showing me that I cannot change it from default levels its not clickable.

Comment: so closing the side log bar enables the selection but i still do not see the respons from the console.log i am sending .